# Google Map Disappearing

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create an effect similar to that of the one found over at [jQuery for Designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/). The problem that I'm having is that when the sidebar begins to scroll, the Google map that is contained inside disappears. I've tested this in Safari & Firefox and the problem only seems to exist in Safari.

You can see my markup for problem at:

https://github.com/kyledecot/skateparks-web/blob/master/app/views/skateparks/index.html.erb

I've also uploaded a short video to show the problem:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/skateparks/5908238246/

The really weird thing that is the map is still there and if you click and drag where the map used to be then it will reappear. Also, if you scroll down (the map disappears), and then you drag around until the map comes back the problem will then be gone until t the next page load.

Answer (score 0):

ok it's really strange!...

Could I suggest to check the CSS? Please try to disable CSS in the browser...
Second option, if it's possible, remove any other javascript from the page, use Google Maps API only.

Let me know! F.

UPDATE:-----------------------
Sorry, I didn't see the linked page... probably it's some css property that doesn't work well with the map container. Checking the CSS (Firebug or similar), and check if all the CSS properties are used (or if there are some properties overridden from the map control).

Answer (score 0):

In the upper right corner you will find "Sign in". Just sign in, I assume it is a Google Account sign in.  I tried a few times and finally hit on one of my sign in accounts that worked.  The next time and all successive times that I went to Google Maps I saw the street show up and stay.  Before they would disappear after a second or two.  Try it, if you don't have a sign in, you just might have to figure out how to set one up.